# How do we frost-proof an outdoor faucet in a home with no crawl space or basement?

Tags: faucet, waterproofing

How do we frost-proof an outdoor faucet in our brick home that's on a slab?

Comment: Installing an insulating bell over it can help. Draining it can help more, if there's an internal cut-off valve you can close and leave closed for the winter. (One hopes the faucet's piping does not run through the slab, but...)

Comment: Are we talking about garden hose bibs: http://www.masterplumber.net/hose_bib/hose_bib.htm or a sink?

Comment: And there is no cutoff valve inside the house?

Comment: Can you provide more details about where the faucet is located and how the water line runs from the house through to the exterior? There are a lot of potential solutions, but the right one depends on the details of your problem.